# Write semi-colon seperated email addresses into a csv file

Tags: python, string, csv, email

I have a file email.txt which has email addresses as follows:

> James, Brian < brian.james@abc.com>; Attar, Daniel < Daniel.Attar@abc.com>; Alex, James < james.alex@abc.com>; Trendy, Elizabeth < elizabeth.trendy@abc.com>; jones, Gary < Gary.Jones@abc.com>; bones, byron < byron.bones@abc.com>;

I want to write the email addresses into a .csv file in one column like this:

```
brian.james@abc.com  
daniel.attar@abc.com  
...  
byron.bones@abc.com
```

I wrote a Python script as follows which does this:

```
    fn1 = "email.txt"
    f1 = open(fn1,"r")
    f1r1 = f1.readlines()
    f1r2 = [i.strip() for i in f1r1]
    f1r3 = [i.split(";") for i in f1r2]
    s1 = f1r3[0]
    a = open("ef.csv","w")
    for i in s1:
        j = i.split("<")
        a.write(j[1].strip(">")+"\n")
    a.close()
```

Is there a better, more efficient or more elegant way to write this?

Comment: @Alpha Delta, first you have to define efficient. Secondly, if it works, and you want simply to ask how to do it better, check out [stack exchange code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider reading the contents of the text file as a single string and then using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract the emails from that string.

In this case, it looks like your email format is fairly specific, so the regex below is also specific also.  Realize, though, that a regex capable of finding any RFC 5322-compliant email address (the "official standard" for email address formats) is several hundred characters long.  For more on that see [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) from Jan Goyvaerts.

Anyway...

```
import re

with open('emails.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Produces a single string, `emails`
    emails = file.read().replace('\n', '')

regex = re.compile('\S+\.\S+@abc\.com')

for email in regex.findall(emails):
    print(email)
# brian.james@abc.com
# Daniel.Attar@abc.com
# james.alex@abc.com
# elizabeth.trendy@abc.com
# Gary.Jones@abc.com
# byron.bones@abc.com
```

Regex walkthrough: this regex assumes each email takes a pretty specific form: `something<dot>somethingelse<at>abc.com`.

- `\S+` is 1 or more non-whitespace characters
- `\.` is a literal period (backslashing a metacharacter)